# How do you add an iad to a tabbarcontroller properly without using IB?

Tags: iphone

I am able to add an iAd Banner View to my tab bar controller with no problem.  The issue comes with the rendering.  The Banner View is drawn overtop of the navigation bar in my interface.

How can I push the navigation bar down or is their a better approach?  I need to do this all programmatically without IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating the ADBannerView programmatically, you can set the coordinates in -initWithFrame:

```
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, YYYY, 0, 0)];
```

where YYYY is the desired Y-location for the ad.  Hope this helps!